# Stanford NLP Server:: Unknown annotator: sentiment

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, stanford-nlp-server

I just downloaded and ran Standfor NLP 3.6.0 http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/index.html
 by using the following command:

```
java -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer --public --port 1062
```

I tested other annotators like POS, Tokenizer and they work just ok. However, when I try to run sentiment annotator[ http://nlp.stanford.edu/sentiment/ ] I get following errors:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown annotator: sentiment
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.ensurePrerequisiteAnnotators(StanfordCoreNLP.java:281)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer$CoreNLPHandler.getProperties(StanfordCoreNLPServer.java:476)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer$CoreNLPHandler.handle(StanfordCoreNLPServer.java:350)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:79)
    at sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:83)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:82)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(ServerImpl.java:675)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:79)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(ServerImpl.java:647)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I uploaded all the files I got from the download page[http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/index.html#download] not sure what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are experiencing the same issue, please download the project from [github](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP) and not from their website. Make sure you have the [models](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-corenlp-models-current.jar) jar, [English](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-english-corenlp-models-current.jar) and ejml model.

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

3.6.0 did not work for me either when trying to run the `sentiment` annotator. 3.7.0 however worked out of the box. Download it [here](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/index.html). Then run it with `java -mx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -port 9000 -timeout 15000` as documented in http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html. e.g. run it with curl `curl --data 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.' 'http://localhost:9000/?properties={%22annotators%22%3A%22tokenize%2Cssplit%2Cparse%2Csentiment%22%2C%22outputFormat%22%3A%22json%22}'`